# How do you format datetime column in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a Dataframe column with the date and time combined as a single int, How can I convert it to a standard Date/Time format?

```
      Date-time
0  202205220000
1  202205220005
2  202205220010
3  202205220015
4  202205220020
5  202205220025
6  202205220030
7  202205220035
8  202205220040
9  202205220045
10 202205220050
11 202205220055
12 202205220100
```

to

```
          Date-time
0  2022-05-22 00:00
1  2022-05-22 00:05
2  2022-05-22 00:10
3  2022-05-22 00:15
4  2022-05-22 00:20
5  2022-05-22 00:25
6  2022-05-22 00:30
7  2022-05-22 00:35
8  2022-05-22 00:40
9  2022-05-22 00:45
10 2022-05-22 00:50
11 2022-05-22 00:55
12 2022-05-22 01:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `format` as parameter of [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['Date-time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date-time'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M')
print(df)

# Output
             Date-time
0  2022-05-22 00:00:00
1  2022-05-22 00:05:00
2  2022-05-22 00:10:00
3  2022-05-22 00:15:00
4  2022-05-22 00:20:00
5  2022-05-22 00:25:00
6  2022-05-22 00:30:00
7  2022-05-22 00:35:00
8  2022-05-22 00:40:00
9  2022-05-22 00:45:00
10 2022-05-22 00:50:00
11 2022-05-22 00:55:00
12 2022-05-22 01:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with the `'%Y%m%d%H%M'` format:

```
df['Date-time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date-time'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M')
```

output:

```
             Date-time
0  2022-05-22 00:00:00
1  2022-05-22 00:05:00
2  2022-05-22 00:10:00
3  2022-05-22 00:15:00
4  2022-05-22 00:20:00
5  2022-05-22 00:25:00
6  2022-05-22 00:30:00
7  2022-05-22 00:35:00
8  2022-05-22 00:40:00
9  2022-05-22 00:45:00
10 2022-05-22 00:50:00
11 2022-05-22 00:55:00
12 2022-05-22 01:00:00
```